# How to build a list of heterogeneous dependant pairs in Coq

Tags: list, types, coq

I'd like to be able to have an heterogeneous sequence of dependent pairs `(T, f)` where `T` is in `Set` and `f` if a function `T -> bool` such as

```
Definition classif :
  seq (forall T : Set, T -> bool) :=
  [:: (fun b : bool => b); (fun n : nat => false)].
```

Note: I'm using SSReflect syntax for lists.
Clearly the type written above is not the right one.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ThéoWinterhalter's answer is the way to go here. Just add a precision w.r.t. his answer [I initially posted it as a comment but that hindered the readability of the code…]:

the type you are looking for here is `{T : Set & T -> bool}`, it is a **Σ-type** and relies on the following inductive:

```
Print sigT.

Inductive sigT (A : Type) (P : A -> Type) : Type :=
    existT : forall x : A, P x -> {x : A & P x}
```

And to ease your definition of `classif`, you could also define a shortcut:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Definition sigma (T' : Set) f := (existT (fun A : Set => A -> bool) T' f).

Definition classif :
  seq {T : Set & T -> bool} :=
[:: sigma (fun b : bool => b); sigma (fun n : nat => false)].
```

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't realise that sigT was sufficient. I finally made my own record.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for dependent pairs and are writing dependent functions instead.
The type of pointed types is

```
{ A : Set & A }
```

Then you can build for instance the pair of `nat` and `1`:

```
Check (existT (fun A : Set => A) nat 1) : { A : Set & A }.
```

It is nicer with some notations but there you have it.